# How to set width 100% only for col-xs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In col-md and col-lg the widht is 50% and stays the way I want. But in col-xs and col-sm the blocks are side by side and not below the other as I want. how to solve?

Comment: Please translate to English for this site.

Comment: Cara, tem uma versão do stack overflow em portugues: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: thanks. i am using.

Comment: Language conversion from Portuguese to English

Comment: col-xs-12 to get 100% width

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak Portuguese, but maybe you should write `col-xs-12` to get `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

You can play different sizes in base of the screen, something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12"></div>
```